# What's an easy, quick way to reload a webapp in tomcat in dev environment?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat 6 on Windows. I've got the "Monitor Tomcat" system tray icon which allows me to start and shutdown Tomcat, but is there another little tool that allows me to easily reload my web app when I've changed the class files? I know the "manager" app that comes with Tomcat has a redeploy option, but just wondering if there's a native app that would do this a bit quicker and nicer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583502/how-do-i-update-a-tomcat-webapp-without-restarting-the-entire-service/6584259#6584259 which I'm going to describe as the "de facto canonical" question for restarting webapps in Tomcat, even though it was asked later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a `reloadable=true` attribute to the `Context`. Quoting the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html):

> Set to `true` if you want Catalina to monitor classes in `/WEB-INF/classes/` and `/WEB-INF/lib` for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for this attribute is `false`. You can use the [Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you've already set `reloadable=true`, you can `touch` either the war file in the webapps directory, or a monitored file such as WEB-INF/web.xml in the exploded application directory. This will update the time stamp and make the app look new, so it will be reloaded.

At our company, we run our Web app servers in dev mode all the time just to facilitate this. To hell with the recommendation, we know better than to run our app on 99% load so we can't spare a few cycles.