# Restart of Apache Tomacat

Tags: java, tomcat

When we change any code in servlet we need to restart Apache ,but when we change any code in JSP we need not restart Apache. Even though at last JSP is turned to Servlet.I

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the question here.

Comment: Possible dupe of possible question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800784/whats-an-easy-quick-way-to-reload-a-webapp-in-tomcat-in-dev-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also enable servlet reloading:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Comment: See also, Manager App HOW-TO: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html