# How to hot-deploy jsp file to tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I don't want to build a war file each time I make a little edit in a JSP file. I want things to work like with PHP. How can I hot-deploy to a tomcat server? Is hot-deploy a java standard?

Can this kind of hot-deploy be used in a released version of my software ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885551/tomcat-hot-deploy

Comment: FYI JSR-88 describes the Java EE deployment standard: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/j2ee_deployment-1.2-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/j2ee_deployment-1_2-mrel-spec.pdf. From my experience frequent hot-deployment often cause the class not released from memory and causing OOME PermGen exception.

Comment: Use an exploded war and copy the JSP file over.

Comment: JRebel is a good tool for hot deployment. It also supports reinitialization of your beans if you use a DI framework. But if it's just a JSP file then all you need to do is to copy the file over

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the linked question doesn't really go into details ...

In `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xm`l, you need to configure the local server to unpack WARs. Here's the example from my development server:

```
 <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" 
       deployXML="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

By default, Tomcat will check for changes to JSP files. In fact, you have to change that for production, as described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Production%20Configuration).

With these changes in place, you will find your web-app in `$CATALINA_BASE/work/Catalina/localhost` (assuming, again, a default install; if you're configuring server name, it won't be `localhost`). Edit the file in-place, and the changes will appear when you load the page next.

> Is this kind of hot-deploy can be used in a release versioin of my software

Not if you want to avoid hard-to-track-down bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today and using an exploded .war just didn't cut it for me.

My solution was to also use the following context.xml file in Tomcat (`$CATALINA_BASE\conf\context.xml`):

```
<Context reloadable="true"> 
    <Resources cachingAllowed="false" cacheMaxSize="0" />

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

I also used the following in my Jsp's for the client side cache:

```
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
%>
```

after tomcat restart it was possible to just copy the Jsp's to `$CATALINA_BASE\webapps\<context>\WEB-INF\...`

and do a quick reload (F5) in my browser to see the changes.

Bonus: Tomcat also does a reload on all its ressources when i copy .class or .jar files into /WEB-INF now :)

Comment: by does a reload you mean it redeploy/restarts the webapp?  Anyway, it appears that WatchedResource only *adds* additional things it watches, and that if you have `reloadable=true` it automatically also watches web.xml and WEB-INF/lib/* as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1800802/32453