# How to dynamically add html/jsp page in tomcat web app(dev environment)

Tags: java, tomcat

When tomcat starts, it created one web app example which currently doesn't have test.html.
Tomcat also has my java agent which listen on specific port and get new contents.
I will receive contents of test.html in java agent. But i am unable to add this page in tomcat context so that when user access this page, he gets new page and not 404 error.
I don't want to create new file under web app folder. Is there a way to add new contents in tomcat context.
I want to do this only in dev enviornment.

Comment: A possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012693/how-to-hot-deploy-jsp-file-to-tomcat

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the info in the linked duplicate, but you shouldn't, at least not in production. That method is useful only for test environments.

J2EE apps were not meant to be updated dynamically, they were meant to be built and then deployed.

Comment: I only intended to do it in dev environment, I updated question with this details