# Tomcat displaying JSP after deleting the class in the /work directory

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

So I have some JSP's that are working fine.  I want to make a direct change as a test to the .java file that jasper creates in the /work directory.

I make the change.  I delete the compiled .class file,  delete the /tmp directory,  and restart tomcat.

When I navigate to the page,  the change I made to the java file is not there.  I go back to the /work directory,  and there is no re-compiled .class file either.

How can that be?  If I go to the page, and there is no class file,  how does it even run?  I would expect tomcat to re-compile the java and create a new class file.

What's going on here?

UPDATE

So I deleted the work directory and re-deploy the war, and restated tomcat.  I navigate back to the page,  and this time, the .java is not even in the work directory.  The directory path is there,  but no java.  Does someone have an article or tutorial they could point me at that goes over how tomcat does this?

Comment: Tomcat can detect that there is no class file and recompile existing JSP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012693/how-to-hot-deploy-jsp-file-to-tomcat

Comment: Right,  but does tomcat just do that in memory?  When I re-start tomcat and navigate to the page, there is still no class file.