# mvn tomcat7:deploy not work if no restart tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, tomcat7-maven-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a war on tomcat via maven (mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy). The deployment seems to work fine, but the application only works if I restart tomcat. It is normal? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tomcat7:deploy](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) only responsible to put the updated WAR file to Tomcat:

> Deploy a WAR to Tomcat.

To use Tomcat hot deploy when war file changes, see [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191689/how-to-overwrite-war-files-during-tomcat-hot-deployment)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Your answer has been useful. Also my problem was that in my context tomcat had the properties activated to not block the files, I do not know why but this causes the application does not start correctly. I have to look for the right way to do both, since my objective activating those properties was to be able to redeploy the application. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By setting `contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>` like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <path>/yourApp</path>
            <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

you get a workaround: tomcat reloads the application whenever detects a change. It's not hot-deploy but, at least, you don't restart it manually.